# Reduce values ​of a variable that is defined with the value of a function

Tags: c++, decrement

I'm looking for a way to reduce the value of a variable that takes its value from a function. However, until now I haven't thought of anything.

The way it is written, the code currently will always return the value of the function.

```
std::string Barger::ShowMessage() {

    int var = Barger::get().var();

    char mes[20];

    sprintf_s(mes, sizeof(mes), "Value Var %d", var--);

    return std::string(mes);
}
```

What I need is that every time the `std::string Barger::ShowMessage()` function is executed it will be reduced by **-1** from the variable, but the function `Barger::get().var()` is not allowing this.

Comment: Have you tried `Barger::get().var() - 1`?

Comment: try to use `static int var = Barger::get().var();`. This way, its only call the function once, and the value of the variable exists among several function calls

Comment: @Beta this does not solve why if the value is for example **500-1** it will be **499** it will always return this value

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff I already tried to use static without success. It starts the counter at zero even the value of the function `Barger::get ().Var();` be a value well above

Comment: If you don't show how `var` function is defined, we cannot know why it always returns the same value! `var--` in the above code is totally useless since it is a post decrement of a local variable that is never used afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not saving the result of `operator--` anywhere other than in a local variable, so every time you call `ShowMessage()`, you are retrieving the same original value again and again.  You need something more like the following, which you will have to add if you do not already have it:

```cpp
std::string Barger::ShowMessage() {

    int var = Barger::get().var();

    char mes[20];

    sprintf_s(mes, sizeof(mes), "Value Var %d", var--);

    Barger::get().setvar(var); // <-- here

    return std::string(mes);
}
```

Unless you can change `var()` to return a non-const `int&` reference to some internal `int` variable, rather than returning an `int` copy of it:

```cpp
std::string Barger::ShowMessage() {

    int& var = Barger::get().var();

    char mes[20];

    sprintf_s(mes, sizeof(mes), "Value Var %d", var--);

    return std::string(mes);
}
```